# Container Managed Transaction with JDO/DataNucleus

Tags: jndi, jdo, datanucleus

Goodmorning all,

I'm currently playing with Datanucleus/JDO. One thing that I like is the Type safe query system, and I want to use Datanucleus in future projects (I come from Hibernate background).
I want to let the container (JBOSS 5) manage the transaction and I've defined a data source following the instructions from a datanucleus user ([datanucleus forum thread](http://www.jpox.org/servlet/forum/viewthread_thread,5774)), the only problem is that i cannot understand how to get a JDOPersistenceManager, all i get from a jndi lookup is the PersistenceManager, if I try a cast to JDOPersistenceManager i will get ClassCastException.
I need the JDOPersistenceManager to get a typesafe query...
My configuration is the same as the one explained in the thread..

Does someone encountered the same problem before?
And I wander also IF this thing would be possible at all...

Thank you for the replies!

Comment: If you get a PM then you can easily let us know what is the fully-qualified class name of that PM. That tells you what you can cast it to

Comment: The instance I receive from the jndi lookup is an instance of the class org.datanucleus.jdo.connector.PersistenceManagerImpl. I Think I need an instance of JDOPersistenceManager, maybe I have to specify it somewhere in datasource configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never had the time to try it under JCA so no obvious access point for getting the underlying JDOPersistenceManager ... however, try something like this

```
JDOPersistenceManager jdopm = 
    ((JDOTransaction)pm.getCurrentTransaction()).getPersistenceManager();
```

and if that works then you have a workaround until we provide an accessor in the 
*org.datanucleus.jdo.connector.PersistenceManagerImpl* class for the JDOPersistenceManager